# Webservice with eclipse,tomcat6,axis2 problem

Tags: eclipse, web-services, tomcat, apache-axis, tomcat6

when i'm trying to make a webservice with eclipse & tomcat v6.0 & axis2, i'm getting an error called

```
This Web axisService has deployment faults
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis2.classloader.JarFileClassLoader cannot be cast to org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentClassLoader at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.populateService(ServiceBuilder.java:131) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.buildServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:101) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.processServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:178) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:82) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:661) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:337) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:241) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadServices(DeploymentEngine.java:131) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.loadServices(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:284) at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:95) at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:567) at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:452) at org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet.init(AxisAdminServlet.java:56) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4420) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4733) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754) at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289) at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Does anyone knows why?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you make sure you don't have duplicate Axis 2 jars in your application classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Version problem. I solved it using ApacheAxis2 **Version 1.5.2.**
Source: *Personal Experience, I faced the same problem and it worked for me!*